# Wordpress does not load custom fonts

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I am more or less new to Wordpress, therefore please be lenient with me.
I want to use a custom hosted font and therefore I added following code to my themes `style.css`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Courier Prime";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("fonts/Courier_Prime/CourierPrime-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
    src: url("fonts/Courier_Prime/CourierPrime-Regular.woff") format("woff");
    src: url("fonts/Courier_Prime/CourierPrime-Regular.woff2") format("woff2");
}
```

and added the custom class `courier` to the elements to use the other font.

The custom css part looks like this:

```
.courier {
    font-family: "Courier Prime", monospace !important;
}
```

But the result renders another font (seems like it uses the "monospace" font of macOS, not "Courier Prime"):

[image: image shows that the "Menlo" font is being used]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check you devtools network tab. Quite likely, there's something wrong with your font path. Otherwise, another css rule might override your style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem quite easily through another method:

I added the font data to my themes `theme.json`:

```
{
                    "fontFace": [
                        {
                            "fontFamily": "Courier Prime",
                            "fontStretch": "normal",
                            "fontStyle": "normal",
                            "fontWeight": "400",
                            "src": [
                                "file:./assets/fonts/courier-prime/CourierPrime-Regular.woff2"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "fontFamily": "Courier Prime",
                            "fontStretch": "normal",
                            "fontStyle": "italic",
                            "fontWeight": "400",
                            "src": [
                                "file:./assets/fonts/courier-prime/CourierPrime-Italic.woff2"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "fontFamily": "Courier Prime",
                            "fontStretch": "normal",
                            "fontStyle": "normal",
                            "fontWeight": "700",
                            "src": [
                                "file:./assets/fonts/courier-prime/CourierPrime-Bold.woff2"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "fontFamily": "Courier Prime",
                            "fontStretch": "normal",
                            "fontStyle": "italic",
                            "fontWeight": "700",
                            "src": [
                                "file:./assets/fonts/courier-prime/CourierPrime-BoldItalic.woff2"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "fontFamily": "\"Courier Prime\", monospace",
                    "name": "Courier Prime",
                    "slug": "courier-prime"
},
```

After that I was able to set the font via custom css **and** directly in the "typography" style tab of Gutenberg.